# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError - Trying to reach a specific value

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to parse a JSON object which is -

```
{
  "ticket": {
    "ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
    "ticket_status": 1,
    "ticket_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM",
    "ticket_replied": false,
    "ticket_reply_message": "None",
    "ticket_issued_by": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
    "ticket_issued_to": "1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg1"
    },
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e88f0a7dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:59 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg3"
    },
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad05-80e8890a5dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:49 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Firstly I need to get into 'messages' and then get id and other values of each of message. To do so I use -

```
{% if ticket_data["messages"] %}
    {% for msg in ticket_data["messages"] %}
        {{ ticket_data['messages'][msg]['msg_id'] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But I do get an error which is `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element {'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg1'}`

What I'm doing wrong? what's the proper way to get a value from it?
I tried using `{{ ticket_data['messages'][msg]['msg_id'] }}` In the for loop, then I do get an ID from the message but 3 times because there are 3 messages defined in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it with:

```
{% if ticket_data["messages"] %}
    {% for msg in ticket_data["messages"] %}
        {{ msg['msg'] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```